# Does matlab have modules?

Tags: matlab

I want to create a file for some utility functions, ie: `utils.m`, where utils would export a list of functions. But so far as I know, matlab can only export one function per `.m` file that takes on the name of the file? How do I get around this?

Comment: Take a look at [packages](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html)

Comment: You could do it the way the toolboxes work, make a file per function and just export the directory, or add it to your path.

Answer (score 7):

You don't really "get around" this - but it sounds like for this use case, packages would be an idea:

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html

In your case, put all utility functions into a directory called `+utils`:

```
+utils
    foo.m
    bar.m
```

Then you can call `foo` and `bar` via

```
utils.foo(...)
```

If you really want all functions in one m-file, you could make `utils` a class with only static functions, something like:

```
classdef utils

methods (Static)
    function foo(..)
    end

    function bar(..)
    end
end

end
```